# How can I set up foreign_key_constraint on model deletion with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have 2 models, `User` and `Role`. `User` `has_many` `Roles`. I set up foreign key constraint also (you can't delete role if there is any user who has this role).

I get error when I'm trying to implement

```
Role
|> Repo.get(id)
|> Repo.delete
```

The error is:

```
 ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to delete struct:

     * foreign_key: users_role_id_fkey

 If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
 call foreign_key_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
 constraint name. The changeset defined the following constraints:

     * foreign_key: roles_users_fkey
```

I have no idea about how to add this `foreign_key_constraint` on deletion. I tried to write it by myself, like:

```
def delete_changeset(struct) do
  struct
  |> cast(%{}, [])
  |> foreign_key_constraint(:users)
end
```

and inserted it before `|> Repo.delete`. But it doesn't work. How can I add `foreign_key_constraint` here?

**UPDATE**

Migration files:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateRole do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:roles) do
      add :name, :string, null: false

      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index(:roles, [:name])
  end
end
```

Add `role_id` to users:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.AddRoleIdToUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    alter table(:users) do
      add :role_id, references(:roles, on_delete: :nothing)
      remove :role
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `|> foreign_key_constraint(:roles)`?

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. The same error message

Comment: Can you please include the migration files you used to generate these tables?

Comment: Dear @Dogbert, done!

Comment: How about `|> assoc_constraint(:role)` (no `foreign_key_constraint`)?

Comment: cannot add constraint to changeset because association `roles` does not exist

Comment: Did you type in `:roles` instead of `:role` by mistake?

Comment: @Dogbert I can't get it. Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the question before. The database constraint is on the `users` table while you're getting the error when deleting a `Role`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by

```
|> foreign_key_constraint(:users, name: :users_role_id_fkey)
```

in delete changeset. But it returns terrible error

```
%{ "users" => ["doesn't exist"] }
```

in the changeset. What the hell? I want to have correct error in the changeset

Comment: I think this is the correct approach. You'll just have to change the message yourself as Ecto defaults to "does not exist". Try: `|> foreign_key_constraint(:users, name: :users_role_id_fkey, message: "exist with this role")` or any better message.

Answer (score 1):

```
Role
|> Repo.get(id)
|> Ecto.Changeset.change
|> Ecto.Changeset.no_assoc_constraint(:users)
|> Repo.delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Still needed this in 2023.

My solution was to tell parent to delete children:

```
  schema "teams" do
    has_many :user_teams, UserTeam, on_delete: :delete_all
  end
```

This way `delete_changeset()` is not needed at all, neither is `no_assoc_constraint()`.